# duplicate multiple numbers in excel

Tags: excel, list, date, autofill

I am trying to create a database in excel. I have a chronological list of 365 dates and I want to be able to fill in 100 cells for each date in a single row.

DATE

1/1/2018 (listed 100 times)

1/2/2018 (listed 100 times)

1/3/2018 (listed 100 times)

(1,36500)

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I'm trying create a spreadsheet that has 365 dates listed 100 times each in a single row. So for instance, 1/1/2018 would be in rows 1-100 , date 1/2/2018 would be in rows 101-201, 1/3/2018 would be in rows 102-202 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In A1:

```
=DATE(2018,1,1) + FLOOR((ROW()-1)/100,1)
```

fill down to required point

Answer (score 0):

You just highlight the first cell in the row, Cut and then select the next 100 cells and paste it in.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do it by copy and paste but to copy and past 365 dates will take a long time. I didn't know if there was a simpler way to do it.